# Is this combinatorial identity a special case of Saalschutz's theroem?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

When I solved a question, the following combinatorial identity was used
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k{n\choose k}{n+k\choose k}{k\choose j}=(-1)^n{n\choose j}{n+j\choose j}.
$$
But to prove this identity is difficulty for me. I think it may be a special case of the Saalschutz's theroem, wchich is stated as follows
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-n)_k(a)_k(b)_k}{(1)_k(c)_k(1+a+b-c-n)_k}=\frac{(c-a)_n(c-b)_n}{(c)_n(c-a-b)_n},
$$
where $(a)_k=a\cdot (a+1)\cdots (a+k-1)$. If it isn't the special case of Saalschutz's theroem, can you present a proof of this identity? All hints, proofs and references are welcome.

Comment: nice question ...........+1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result is more easily proved without the use of Saalschutz' theorem.

A good starting point for evaluating such sums may be to write them out in terms of factorials:
$$
(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{k}{j}
=\frac{(-1)^k\,n!\,(n+k)!\,k!}{k!\,(n-k)!\,k!\,n!\,j!\,(k-j)!}
=\frac{(-1)^k\,(n+k)!}{k!\,(n-k)!\,j!\,(k-j)!}
$$
for $j\le k\le n$ (otherwise the LHS is zero). I often think of the sum as over all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, but with the convention that $1/r!=0$ when $r$ is a negative integer.

You may note that $k$ appears in four of the factorials. This means we can try to rewrite the expression so that we may use the rule
$$
\sum_k\binom{a}{p+k}\binom{b}{q-k}=\binom{a+b}{p+q}
$$
where $a$ or $b$ may be negative using the conversion
$$
\binom{-(m+1)}{k}
=(-1)^k\binom{m+k}{k}
=(-1)^k\binom{m+k}{m}.
$$
We may do so as
$$
\frac{(-1)^k\,(n+k)!}{k!\,(n-k)!\,j!\,(k-j)!}
=(-1)^k\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{n-j}{n-k}\binom{n}{j}
=\binom{-(n+1)}{k}\binom{n-j}{n-k}\binom{n}{j}
$$
which gives us the sum
$$
\sum_k\binom{-(n+1)}{k}\binom{n-j}{n-k}\binom{n}{j}
=\binom{-(j+1)}{n}\binom{n}{j}
=(-1)^n\binom{n+j}{j}\binom{n}{j}.
$$

---

As Darij pointed out, the result could be obtain a little more directly (without writing out all the factorials) by using
$$
\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{j}=\binom{n}{j}\binom{n-j}{n-k}.
$$
Of course, since I never remember these kinds of rules, I personally have to write this out as factorials anyway, but doing so only for these two binomials is a bit simpler than doing it for all three (and more so in more complicated cases).

Comment: Nice argument! But the fractions don't really work when $k < j$; it is better to argue $\dbinom{n}{k}\dbinom{k}{j} = \dbinom{n}{j}\dbinom{n-j}{n-k}$ using the $\dbinom{a}{b} = \dfrac{1}{b!} a\left(a-1\right)\cdot\left(a-b+1\right)$ formula.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: True. I used, without stating so, the convention that $1/r!=0$ when $r$ is a negative integer: alternatively, specifying that $j\le k$. Will add a comment to that effect in the answer.

Comment: @Einar Rødland, Thank you for your nice answer.

Answer (score 8):

Multiply the desired identity by $(-1)^n$ to get

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}k\binom{n+k}k\binom{k}j=\binom{n}j\binom{n+j}j\;,$$

and rewrite it as

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k\binom{2n-k}{n-k}\binom{n-k}j=\binom{n}j\binom{n+j}n\;.\tag{1}$$

We may assume that $j\le n$. You have $2n$ white balls numbered from $1$ through $2n$. The righthand side of $(1)$ is the number of ways to pick $j$ of the balls from the balls with numbers $1$ through $n$, dump those in a box with the balls numbered $n+1$ through $2n$, and then choose $n$ of the balls in the box and paint them red.

Alternatively, there are $\binom{2n}n\binom{n}j$ ways to choose any $j$ of the balls numbered $1$ through $n$, dump them in a box with the balls numbered $n+1$ through $2n$, and then choose any $n$ of the $2n$ balls to paint red, regardless of whether or not the balls are in the box. Of course some of these outcomes result in red balls *not* in the box, and we want to exclude those.

For $k=1,\ldots,n$ let $B_k$ be the set of outcomes in which ball $k$ ends up red but not in the box. There are $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$ ways to choose the other $n-1$ red balls, and there are $\binom{n-1}j$ ways to choose $j$ balls from the first $n$, *not* including ball $k$, to go into the box. Thus,

$$|B_k|=\binom{2n-1}{n-1}\binom{n-1}j\;.$$

Similarly, if $1\le k<\ell\le n$,

$$|B_k\cap B_\ell|=\binom{2n-2}{n-2}\binom{n-2}j\;,$$

and in general for $1\le k_1<k_2<\ldots k_m\le n$ we have

$$\left|\bigcap_{\ell=1}^mB_{k_\ell}\right|=\binom{2n-m}{n-m}\binom{n-m}j\;,$$

and we see that $(1)$ is just an application of the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Answer (score 4):

The LHS is the coefficient of $x^j$ in:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}(1+x)^k $$
hence we just need to find:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}z^k =\phantom{}_2 F_1(-n,1+n,1,z)=P_n^{(0,0)}(1-2z)$$
that is a Jacobi polynomial, better known as the [shifted Legendre polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Shifted_Legendre_polynomials) $\tilde{P}_n(z)$.

Then your claim just follows from the [Rodrigues' formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_formula).

Answer (score 4):

**Remark.** Incorporates a correction by Markus Scheuer.

Suppose we seek to evaluate

$$S_j(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k}
{n+k\choose k} {k\choose j}$$

which is claimed to be
$$(-1)^n {n\choose j}{n+j\choose j}.$$

Introduce
$${n+k\choose k}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n+k}}{z^{k+1}} \; dz$$

and
$${k\choose j}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{k}}{w^{j+1}} \; dw.$$

This yields for the sum
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n}}{z}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{j+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} \frac{(1+z)^k (1+w)^k}{z^k} 
\; dw \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n}}{z}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{j+1}}
\left(1-\frac{(1+w)(1+z)}{z}\right)^n
\; dw \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n}}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{j+1}}
\left(-1-w-wz\right)^n
\; dw \; dz
\\ = \frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n}}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{j+1}}
\left(1+w+wz\right)^n
\; dw \; dz
.$$

This is
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n}}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{j+1}}
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} w^q (1+z)^q
\; dw \; dz.$$

Extracting the residue at $w=0$ we get
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n}}{z^{n+1}}
{n\choose j} (1+z)^j \; dz
\\ = {n\choose j}  \frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n+j}}{z^{n+1}}\; dz
\\ = (-1)^n {n\choose j} {n+j\choose n}.$$

thus proving the claim.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another variation of the theme (similar to the techniques presented in Marko Riedel's answer).

*Note:* This powerful technique is based upon the [Cauchys residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) and was introduced by *G.P. Egorychev* ([Integral Representation and the Computation of Combinatorial Sums](http://www.amazon.de/Representation-Computation-Combinatorial-Translations-Mathematical/dp/0821845128)) to compute binomial identies.

We use only two aspects of this theory. Let $A(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jz^j$ be a *formal power series*, then

- Write the binomial coeffients as *residuals* of corresponding *formal power series*

\begin{align*}
\mathop{res}_{z}\frac{A(z)}{z^{j+1}}=a_j\tag{1}
\end{align*}

- Apply the *substitution rule* for formal power series:

\begin{align*}
A(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jz^{j}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}z^j\mathop{res}_{w}\frac{A(w)}{w^{j+1}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

We observe:

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}}&\color{blue}{(-1)^k{n\choose k}{n+k\choose k}{k\choose j}}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\mathop{res}_{z}\frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{k+1}}
> \mathop{res}_{u}\frac{(1+u)^{n+k}}{u^{k+1}}
> \mathop{res}_{t}\frac{(1+t)^{k}}{t^{j+1}}\tag{4}\\
> &=\mathop{res}_{u,t}\frac{(1+u)^n}{ut^{j+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left((-1)\frac{(1+u)(1+t)}{u}\right)^k
> \mathop{res}_{z}\frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{k+1}}\tag{5}\\
> &=\mathop{res}_{u,t}\frac{(1+u)^n}{ut^{j+1}}\left(1-\frac{(1+u)(1+t)}{u}\right)^n\tag{6}\\
> &=(-1)^n\mathop{res}_{u,t}\frac{(1+u)^{n}}{u^{n+1}t^{j+1}}\left(1+(1+u)t\right)^n\\
> &=(-1)^n\mathop{res}_{u}\frac{(1+u)^{n}}{u^{n+1}}[t^j]\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(1+u)^kt^k\tag{7}\\
> &=(-1)^n\mathop{res}_{u}\frac{(1+u)^{n}}{u^{n+1}}\binom{n}{j}(1+u)^j\\
> &=(-1)^n\binom{n}{j}\mathop{res}_{u}\frac{(1+u)^{n+j}}{u^{n+1}}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(-1)^n\binom{n}{j}\binom{n+j}{n}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we change the limit to $\infty$ without changing the value, since we add only $0$.
- In (4) we use $(1+z)^n$ as *formal power series* with the coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$ according to (1) and similarly for expressions in $u$ and $t$
- In (5) we do some rearrangement to prepare the application of the *substitution rule*
- In (6) we apply the substitution rule according to (2)
- In (7) we use the [coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216) operator $[t^j]$ to denote the coefficient of $t_j$ in the sum. Observe that following is valid when using the *formal residual operator* $\mathop{res}$

$$\mathop{res}_t\frac{A(t)}{t^{j+1}}=[t^{-1}]t^{-j-1}A(t)=[t^j]A(t)$$

Comment: Please do read my answer. It is exactly the same as yours, and I was first. The summation is the same as are the functions involved. From the point of view of didactics yours is the better answer.

Comment: If I read this correctly your factor of $(-1)^n$ shows up one line too soon and the expansion of the term $1-(1+u)(1+t)$ is incorrrect and the power on $u$ on line seven is off by one.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: I see and you're right. I've added a comment regarding the same techniques. Thanks for your nice statement regarding didactics. Nevertheless +1 for your answer of course. And you're right: Together with Jack D'Aurizios and Brian Scotts answer we have a broad spectrum of different approaches. :-)

Comment: I apologize for the tone. I use the Egorychev method a lot and in fact I learned the name from one of your posts and I do mention it if I remember. Of course this is really the Cauchy Residue Theorem in disguise. I used the method on an unanswered question that I put a bounty on an hour ago.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Don't worry! I appreciate it if typos or errors can be fixed.

Comment: In fact the mistake is in my answer not in yours. I will fix this immediately. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a derivation using *[hypergeometric functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html)*. We will see, OP's binomial identity is not a hypergeometric $_3F_2$ function which is subject to the Saalschütz identity, but a hypergeometric $_2F_1$ function instead, which follows another nice identity.

Here we use the rising factorials notation $(a)_{k}:=a(a+1)\cdots(a+k-1)$.

> Assuming $n>j$ we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=j}^n}&\color{blue}{(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{k}{j}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}\underbrace{(-1)^{k+j}\binom{n}{k+j}\binom{n+k+j}{k+j}\binom{k+j}{j}}_{=:t_k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}t_k=t_0\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}\prod_{q=0}^{k-1}\frac{t_{q+1}}{t_q}\\
> &=(-1)^j\binom{n}{j}\binom{n+j}{j}\\
> &\qquad\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}\prod_{q=0}^{k-1}
> (-1)^{q+1+j}\binom{n}{q+1+j}\binom{n+q+1+j}{q+1+j}\binom{q+1+j}{j}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\cdot(-1)^{-q-j}
> \binom{n}{q+j}^{-1}\binom{n+q+j}{q+j}^{-1}\binom{q+j}{j}^{-1}\\
> &=(-1)^j\binom{n}{j}\binom{n+j}{j}\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}\prod_{q=0}^{k-1}
> \frac{\left(j-n+q\right)\left(j+n+q+1\right)}{\left(q+1\right)\left(j+q+1\right)}\\
> &=(-1)^j\binom{n}{j}\binom{n+j}{j}\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}\frac{(j-n)_k(j+n+1)_k}{(j+1)_k}\,\frac{1}{k!}\\
> &=(-1)^j\binom{n}{j}\binom{n+j}{j}{_2F_1}\left(j-n,j+n+1;j+1;1\right)\tag{1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(-1)^n\binom{n}{j}\binom{n+j}{j}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we write the sum as hypergeometric $_2F_1$ function evaluated at $z=1$ with parameter $j-n$ a negative integer.
- In (2) we recall the *Chu-Vandermonde* identity (see e.g. Corollary 2.2.3 in *[Special Functions](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/special-functions/1F1C575CEA780EE774F5518C7963BF08#fndtn-information)* by G.E. Andrews, R. Askey and R. Roy) which is
  \begin{align*}
  {_2F_1}(-n,a;c;1)=\frac{(c-a)_n}{(c)_n}
  \end{align*}
  We derive from (1)
  \begin{align*}
  {_2F_1}(j-n,j+n+1;j+1;1)&=\frac{(-n)_{n-j}}{(j+1)_{n-j}}\\
  &=\frac{(-n)(-n+1)\cdots(-j-1)}{(j+1)(j+2)\cdots (n)}\\
  &=(-1)^{n-j}
  \end{align*}